# Regex to capture a string after a specific number of whitespaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to grab a specific sub-string within a log message:

**Example:**

```
esx03.mrlab.local dfwpktlogs: 61283 INET match PASS domain-c7/1001 IN 52 TCP 192.168.50.124/60313->192.168.50.122/48002 SEW
```

What I am looking to capture is the string after the 10th whitespace and before the next / mark.

In the above example, I am trying to capture `192.168.50.124`

This string may or may not have an IP address, but it will always follow the 10th space and precede a slash (/).

I have tried a few methods, but I cannot seem to figure out how to begin after the 10th whitespace.

Comment: What is the programming language/tool? What were the "few methods" you tried? Please add a valid tag to the question and update it with your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work for you:

```
^([^\s]+\s){10}([^\/]+)\/.*$
```

This captures `192.168.50.124` in the second capture group.

[Here's](https://regexr.com/52lbt) a link to a RegExr demo.

**Explanation:** breaking down the regex, term by term:

- `^` matches the start of the line.
- `[^\s]+\s` - `[^\s]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), it matches any character other than a whitespace character (`\s`). `[^\s]+\s` matches one or more non-whitespace characters followed by a whitespace character.
- `([^\s]+\s){10}` - this matches the pattern inside the parentheses 10 times, so this matches one or more non-whitespace character, followed by a whitespace character, ten times.
- `([^\/]+)` this matches one or more character that is not a forward slash.  Note how we have to escape the forward slash (`\/`).  Enclosing this in parentheses allows us to access it later as a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
- `\/.*` matches a forward slash followed by zero or more of any other character.
- `$` matches the end of the line.

Comment: OP's questions are mostly about MS SQL that does not support regex based extraction like this.

Comment: Where in his question does he mention MSSQL?

Comment: Same as nowhere is it mentioned OP can use a JavaScript/PCRE regex syntax.

Comment: it is actually for a tool we use to extract fields...the system uses regular expressions, so no MSSQL...

Comment: actually, I am having difficulty with the application understanding the capture group...is there a regex expression that will return the needed string without it being grouped?

Comment: Impossible I'm afraid @Buckwheattb, the _only_ thing that we know about the text that you want to capture is its position in the text as a whole ("it will always follow the 10th space and precede a slash (/)").  Sorry.

Comment: I found this alternative:
^(?:[^\s]+\s){10}([^\/]+)\/.*$

Adding the ?: to the first group negates it as a return group...that settled it down and grabbed the right value.